# Calling the stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql

```
CALL rebuild;
```

How would i call this each and every time dynamically without doing a query in database. I mean each time i update some value, i need to call this to make sure the changes are in effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use a trigger.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 1):

You could look at triggers? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html
Though they're generally avoided as they tend to make it harder to follow what you're app is doing.

You could also amend your data-access code to automatically append this command to any relevant update/insert that's happening?